# 3 subspaces $A, B, C$ of linear space $V$ and $A + B = A + C \ iff B = C$ and $dim (B) = dim(C) \iff dim (A \cap B) = dim (A \cap C)$

Tags: linear-algebra

There are $3$ subspaces $A, B, C$ of linear space $V$ and $A + B = A + C$.

Then it means that: $B = C$ and that $dim (B) = dim(C) \iff dim (A \cap B) = dim (A \cap C)$. Am I thinking right?

I am trying to get better understanding of that subject.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11168/290189) Please read [this post](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/290189) and the others there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include some motivation, and an explanation of your own attempts.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}=\mathbb{R}+\mathbb{R}=\mathbb{R}+\{0\}$ is a good example to ponder.

Comment: Oh, I get it now. So $A =/= B$ and $dim(A) =/= dim(B)$

Comment: But is R a subspace of R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $V=\mathbb{R}^2$, $A=Z(x)$, $B=Z(x-y)$, and $C=Z(2x-y)$ where $Z(f)$ means zeros of $f \in \mathbb{R}[x,y]$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Check that these spaces satisfy the conditions you wrote but $B \neq C$. Besides, the dimension related parts are true.

[image]